# How to decode and cast JSON string in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, json

I'm using [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) to decode/encode JSON strings. In my little experiment I want to encode 
an object (`UserInfo`) to JSON string and decode it back to the object, however it seems to fail at the convertion point (the last line), why would that happen? how can I make it work?

#### The `UserInfo` class

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public var levelProgress    : int;
}
```

#### The conversion code

```
var user1:UserInfo = new UserInfo() 
user1.levelProgress = 20;

var a:String = JSON.encode(user1);
var b:Object = JSON.decode(a);
var c:UserInfo;

c = b as UserInfo;  // c gets null, why?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something similar to what this page says: http://benrimbey.wordpress.com/2009/06/20/reflection-based-json-validation-with-vo-structs/

The problem with your code is you are trying to downcast a native Object into a specific Class instance that it knows nothing about. The structures of your two types are different. UserInfo inherits from Object (in a sort of funky AS3 way because of the way Classes are compiled), but b is a simple Object.

Answer (score 2):

FYI if you are just doing JSON decoding, and it is a Flex app, not AIR. You do not need the as3Corelib package to do so. You can just use the parent browser's JavaScript interpreter like this:

`var myJSONString:String = "{name:'Joe',age:35}";
var myObj:Object = ExternalInterface.call('eval', "("+myJSONString+")");`

This might save your user a few Kb on the download.

Answer (score 1):

Glenn's link really did the trick. I also added a conversion between dot-net and AS3 - it seems that dot-net writes the __type attribute like so: "Class:Namespace", but AS3 needs it to be like so: "Namespace.Class".

```
private static function convertDotNetToASNameType(nameType:String):String            
{
    return(nameType.split(':').reverse().join('.'));
}
```

BTW, if you are using Glenn's link and a WCF server, be sure to replace "clientClassPath" with dot-net's "__type".

Answer (score 0):

Could also do the casting in the VO's constructor.

```
public class YourVO
{

    public var id:int;
    public var prop1:String;
    public var prop2:String;
    public var prop3:String;

    public function YourVO(jsonObject : Object)
    {
        for (var p:String in jsonObject) {
            if( this.hasOwnProperty(p) ){
                this[p] = jsonObject[p];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and use it like so:

```
var yourVO:YourVO = new YourVO( jsonObject );
```